# Why is Entity Framework trying to store my foreign key for a second time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

like the title says: my .SaveChanges() method is trying to insert my Property (ParameterType) again, which should not be the case. The property should just update when a user picks a different item from the Dropdownlistfor. It does not matter if you keep the old ParameterType or choose a different one in the Edit view, the compiler will 10/10 throw this error.

I have an ASP.NET Core application and using Entity Framework Core I have a setup like this:

Model

```
public class Parameter
    {
        public int ParameterId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value{ get; set; }
        public ParameterType  ParameterType { get; set; }

 }
```

View ( Edit )

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" required />


                <label>Value</label>
                <textarea asp-for="Value" class="form-control" required style="width:1250px"> </textarea>
                <label>ParameterType</label>

                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParameterType.ParameterTypeId, new SelectList(Model.ParameterTypes, "ParameterTypeId", "TypeName"), new { @class = "form-control" })



            </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-10">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Confirm</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <a asp-controller="Parameter" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Function to map EVM to Model

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(ParameterEditViewModel parameterEditViewModel, int id)
        {
            Parameter parameter = null;
            parameter = _parameterRepository.GeefParameterMetId(id);

            MapParameterEditViewModelToParameter(parameterEditViewModel, parameter);
            try
            {

                _parameterRepository.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch
            {

               TempData["error"] = $"Edit failure";
            }
            TempData["message"] = $"Parameter Edit success";
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

SaveChanges() throws this exception:

```
The instance of entity type 'ParameterType' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ParameterTypeId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

UPDATE :  MapParameterEditViewModelToParameter Method

```
        private void MapParameterEditViewModelToParameter(ParameterEditViewModel parameterEditViewModel, Parameter parameter)
        {
            parameter.Name= parameterEditViewModel.Naam;
            parameter.Value= parameterEditViewModel.Waarde;
            parameter.ParameterType = parameterEditViewModel.ParameterType;
        }
```

Kind regards,
Glanie

Comment: can you also share your `MapParameterEditViewModelToParameter` method?

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to do this in the first place, done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to extend your `Parameter` class like this:

```
public class Parameter
    {
        public int ParameterId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value{ get; set; }
        public int ParameterTypeId { get; set; } // FK to parameter type
        public ParameterType  ParameterType { get; set; }

 }
```

And then adjust the binding:

```
        private void MapParameterEditViewModelToParameter(ParameterEditViewModel parameterEditViewModel, Parameter parameter)
        {
            parameter.Name= parameterEditViewModel.Naam;
            parameter.Value= parameterEditViewModel.Waarde;
            parameter.ParameterTypeId = parameterEditViewModel.ParameterTypeId; // also change this property name and type to just carry only the Id of parameter type
        }
```

Comment: Gracias! It makes sense, I guess I just overlooked this :-)

Comment: no problem, if it works for you,could you accept this answer so it's clear there is no more need for the solution ?:p